# Can’t uproot GNU GRUB

Tags: grub

Should have explored more within Oracle or on usb drive before duel booting ANY distro. I’ve deleted the partition containing Elementary OS but now my laptop chooses to boot load GNU GRUB as primary. I don’t want it on my laptop. Can someone dig me out of the mess my ignorance has put me in? I don’t know what partition it resides in. I don’t know what I’m looking for in Disk Manager as nothing is jumping out “I’m right here.” I’ve created a Windows recovery USB stick.
I’ve read every thread involving removing GRUB but I still can’t identify the correct partition.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows installed then you can just go inside your firmware/bios and set the first boot device to the Windows Boot Manager.

To delete grub you need to mount the /boot partition and delete some files. However I don't think it's worth the trouble.